# Ubuntu One notes access through API

Tags: notes, ubuntu-one-api

Now that Ubuntu One notes web interface has been binned, I need to write an application for my Blackberry to read my Ubuntu One notes. Can someone point me in the direction of an API resource for notes please?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu One implements Tomboy's REST synchronisation API, which is documented here:

https://live.gnome.org/Tomboy/Synchronization/REST/1.0

Uses `https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/` as the base URL for your API requests (i.e. so the initial request would go to `https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/api/1.0/`).

As described in the Tomboy spec, you will need to authenticate using [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) using the entry points returned by the API.  I don't think we've got a system set up to allow you to register consumer keys yet, but you should be able to use Tomboy's default consumer key and secret of `anyone` and `anyone` in the interim.

We are in the process of building our [developer web site](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/), so this information should be available there in the future.